# Performing piecewise integration

Tags: numerical-integration

The premise is that I am a new Mathematica user.
I'm trying to evaluate the following

```
B[t_, i_, h_] = piecewise[{{(t - (i - 2)*h)^3, (i - 2)*h <= t <= (i - 1)*h}, {h^3 + 
3*h^2*(t - (i - 1)*h) + 3*h*(t - (i - 1)*h)^2 - 3*(t - (i - 1)*h)^3,
(i - 1)*h <= t <= i*h}, {h^3 + 3*h^2*((i + 1)*h - t) + 3*h*((i + 1)*h - t)^2 - 
3*((i + 1)*h - t)^3, i*h <= t <= (i + 1)*h}, {((i + 2)*h - t)^3, (i + 1)*h <= t <= (i + 2)*h}}]

B0 = B[t, 0, h] - 4*B[t, -1, h]
B0p = D[B0, t]
a00p = integrate[B0p[t, h]^2, {t, 0, 1}]
```

But at the end I just get 'integrate[the extended form of B0p]'.
Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Thanks. Using uppercase letters I get the following:
[image]

Comment: Commands need to be capitalised.

Comment: And probably worth avoiding single capitals for functions names to avoid clashes with built in functions.

Comment: To be precise, built-in function names are always capitalized. User developed function may be named with or without caps but preferably don't start with a capital letter.

Comment: You have not defined a function B0p with two arguments, yet you call it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Correcting the syntax errors:

```
B[t_, i_, h_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(t - (i - 2)*h)^3, (i - 2)*h <= t <= (i - 1)*h}, {h^3 + 
     3*h^2*(t - (i - 1)*h) + 3*h*(t - (i - 1)*h)^2 - 
     3*(t - (i - 1)*h)^3, (i - 1)*h <= t <= i*h}, {h^3 + 
     3*h^2*((i + 1)*h - t) + 3*h*((i + 1)*h - t)^2 - 
     3*((i + 1)*h - t)^3, 
    i*h <= t <= (i + 1)*h}, {((i + 2)*h - t)^3, (i + 1)*h <= 
     t <= (i + 2)*h}}]

B0[t_, h_] := B[t, 0, h] - 4*B[t, -1, h]
B0p[t_, h_] := D[B0[t, h], t]
a00p = Integrate[B0p[t, h]^2, {t, 0, 1}]
```

yields:

[image]

you should check this fits your expectations. Please compare code (if my corrections are ok) to understand the syntax errors.